Rviz2 OpenGL error
I am running Ros2 Jazzy on Ubuntu 24 on a Raspberry Pi 5. I have attached an RPLidar A1M8 to it. I want to use it to create a map of my environment, for that, I'm using the Slam_Toolbox.
But I encounter some errors while trying to visualize the map in Rviz2.
Here's my process:
Terminal 1:
$ ros2 launch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/kookaburra/.ros/log/2024-09-22-15-08-45-610837-kookaburra-desktop-5562
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [rplidar_composition-1]: process started with pid [5576]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [5577]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-3]: process started with pid [5578]
[INFO] [throttle-4]: process started with pid [5579]
[throttle-4] /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/topic_tools/throttle: error while loading shared libraries: libthrottle_node.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ERROR] [throttle-4]: process has died [pid 5579, exit code 127, cmd '/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/topic_tools/throttle messages /scan 1.0 --ros-args -r __node:=throttle_scan'].
[static_transform_publisher-3] [WARN] [1726997926.155586386] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-2] [WARN] [1726997926.157821367] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997926.305743382] [rplidar_composition]: RPLIDAR running on ROS 2 package rplidar_ros. SDK Version: '1.12.0'
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1726997926.402724278] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] from 'base_footprint' to 'laser'
[static_transform_publisher-3] [INFO] [1726997926.402725130] [static_transform_publisher_odom]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-3] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-3] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-3] from 'odom' to 'base_footprint'
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997928.845191442] [rplidar_composition]: RPLIDAR S/N: 73B3ED95C4E493CAA5E69EF0E2634B6E
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997928.845341371] [rplidar_composition]: Firmware Ver: 1.29
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997928.845373094] [rplidar_composition]: Hardware Rev: 7
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997928.848253258] [rplidar_composition]: RPLidar health status : '0'
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997928.848555599] [rplidar_composition]: Start
[rplidar_composition-1] [INFO] [1726997929.405372516] [rplidar_composition]: current scan mode: Sensitivity, max_distance: 12.0 m, Point number: 7.9K , angle_compensate: 2, flip_x_axis 0

Ignore the libthrottle_node.so warning, I was trying to create a throttled /scan topic with less frequency (i thought of trying to start with 1/sec), so as to try to not overwhelm my Pi5, but even with Ros2 topic_tools properly installed and the libthrottle_node.so in the correct place, for some reason I keep getting this error.
If someone could help me with that it would be great help.
Terminal 2:
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_sync_launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/kookaburra/.ros/log/2024-09-22-15-09-10-479666-kookaburra-desktop-6034
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [sync_slam_toolbox_node-1]: process started with pid [6054]
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1726997951.501227834] [slam_toolbox]: Node using stack size 40000000
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1726997951.522998663] [slam_toolbox]: Configuring
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1726997951.581808183] [slam_toolbox]: Using solver plugin solver_plugins::CeresSolver
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1726997951.582326270] [slam_toolbox]: CeresSolver: Using SCHUR_JACOBI preconditioner.
[INFO] [launch.user]: [LifecycleLaunch] Slamtoolbox node is activating.
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1726997951.657294195] [slam_toolbox]: Activating
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] Registering sensor: [Custom Described Lidar]

Terminal 3:
$ ros2 run rviz2 rviz2
[INFO] [1726997966.952009172] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[INFO] [1726997966.952122268] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 3.1 (GLSL 1.4)
[INFO] [1726997967.015361690] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[INFO] [1726997976.687578020] [rviz2]: Trying to create a map of size 49 x 57 using 1 swatches
[ERROR] [1726997976.719929643] [rviz2]: rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.vert
rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.frag
 GLSL link result : 
active samplers with a different type refer to the same texture image unit

This is the error part, when I open Rviz2, and subscribe to the /map topic, for the first second, a map begins to take shape, and then this error happens and the map stops to update any further. I have checked by scanning the /scan topic after the crash, and it is fine, it's rviz which is having trouble visualizing the map. See the image below:

I have done:
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

due to some suggestions I read online while trying to debug this issue, but these don't seem to work. I'm not sure if all of this is important, but here are my slam_toolbox params for the lidar, as i read that maybe decreasing the resolution may help with the issue:
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:

    # Plugin params
    solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
    ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
    ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
    ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
    ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
    ceres_loss_function: None

    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan # /throttled_scan
    use_map_saver: true
    mode: mapping #localization

    # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
    # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
    # will use pose
    #map_file_name: test_steve
    #map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    #map_start_at_dock: true

    debug_logging: false
    throttle_scans: 1
    transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 12.0 #for rastering images
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    tf_buffer_duration: 30.
    stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
    enable_interactive_mode: true

    # General Parameters
    use_scan_matching: true
    use_scan_barycenter: true
    minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
    minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
    scan_buffer_size: 10
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
    link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
    link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
    loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
    do_loop_closing: true 
    loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
    loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
    loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
    loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

    # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
    correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
    correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
    correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

    # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
    loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
    loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
    loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

    # Scan Matcher Parameters
    distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
    angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

    fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
    coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
    coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
    minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
    minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
    use_response_expansion: true

I found a question exactly similar to mine, but it has no responses.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907899/error-while-visualizing-map-from-slam-toolbox-on-rviz
